# Out of range value for column '(null)' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE  monthly_report_c a
       LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(a.TRANSACTION_DATE,'%d.%m.%Y')), '%Y%m') mnt, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.CUSTOMER_ID) totalNum
        FROM    spendingtx a
        WHERE   a.CARD_PROGRAM = "visa"
   AND  CAST(a.AMOUNT AS DECIMAL(5,2)) > 0.01
        GROUP   BY DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(a.TRANSACTION_DATE,'%d.%m.%Y')),'%Y%m')
    ) b ON b.mnt = a.Month_Number

.
.
.
SET a.visa = IFNULL(b.totalNum, 0)
```

The code above extracts from `spendingtx` table and updates another table which has the first field as `yearmonth` (i.e. 201309 201310 ... etc)

I'm getting this error:

> [Err] 1264 - Out of range value for column '(null)' at row 1

Comment: Is a.TRANSACTION_DATE NULL for any row.  It could throw that error when you try to turn NULL into a data.  Also, what DBMS are you using?  MYSQL, ORACLE, MSSQL?

Comment: Just crazy thought, you use alias 'a' twice. Even though the second is inside subquery wonder if would screw things up.

Comment: using MYSQL there are no NULL values in TRANSACTION_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Your DBMS seems to be MySQL (mine is *5.6.34 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)*) and the error occurs in `CAST()`.

1. Outside of `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, MySQL throws nothing.

   ```
   SELECT CAST( 12345 AS DECIMAL(3, 2) ) AS f;
   ```

   *Output:*

   ```
   f
   9.99
   ```
2. Inside `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, the error is thrown explicitly.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `t` (
   `c` blob NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

   INSERT INTO t
   SELECT CAST( 12345 AS DECIMAL(3, 2) ) AS f;
   ```

   *Output:*

   ```
   #1264 - Out of range value for column 'f' at row 1
   ```
3. Your message coming from `WHERE` clause is a little strange.

   ```
   INSERT INTO t
   SELECT 1
   FROM t
   WHERE CAST( 12345 AS DECIMAL(3, 2) );
   ```

   *Output:*

   ```
   #1264 - Out of range value for column '(null)' at row 1
   ```